# Meteor: How to make in infinite scrolling page displaying a dynamic collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

On a monitoring system application, 
I publish a small subset of a huge collection as most of the time we don't need more than few documents.

On the Server:

```
Meteor.publish("amon", function() {
    return Mon.find({}, {
        sort: {
            utctime: -1
        },
        limit: 250
    })
})
```

The problem is that sometimes, I need to scroll down in the page, to get more results.
Republishing does not work (error message : Ignoring duplicate publish named 'amon') and is not really an option as it would affect all clients.
Here is the piece of code that detects when we approach end of scrolling of the page, to trigger the load of additional data, but it's always limited to the 250 published documents.

Here is a bit of code showing how I can go to 250 documents displayed:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      var livehistory = Session.get('livehistory')
      if (
          (document.getElementById('tabpage_1').style.display != "none") &&
          ($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop() <= $(window).height() + 100) &&
          (livehistory < 2000)
          )
      {
        console.log("Scrolled Down");
        livehistory = livehistory + 200
        Session.set('livehistory', livehistory)
      } 
      if ($(document).scrollTop() < $(window).height()*0.5) {
        // We're back to normal mode, so reduce displayed history and enable live mode.
        Session.set('livehistory', 80)
        Session.set('live', true)
      } else {  
        Session.set('live', false)
      } 
});
```

Here is the template. (Notice the Reactive that is handy to disable updates when scrolling down).

```
Template.log.loglines = function() {
    var query = Mon.find({}, {
        sort: {
            utctime: -1
        },
        limit: Session.get('livehistory'),
        reactive: Session.get("live") || false
    })
    return query
};
```

How can I get a display of more than 250 documents when scrolling down the page?
Ideally accessing millions of documents, by also using the "skip" to only display (and syncrhonize) the slice of data needed?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you seen [this example from meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Infinite_Scrolling)?

Comment: checkout this package https://atmospherejs.com/package/pages

Comment: Thanks user728291, it' looks like the example from meteorpedia is exactly what I am looking for. For the atmosphere package, it could make it, but first they need to fix the reactivity problem.

Comment: The example from Meteorpedia worked for me. I was not aware tha we could send arguments to the publish this way. This is the solution I was looking for. Thanks !